# Why is $\frac{x}{(1-x)}$ on $[0,1)$ injective?

Tags: real-analysis

For one to one, $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$. Then $\displaystyle\frac{x}{1-x} = \displaystyle\frac{y}{1-y} \Rightarrow x(1-y) = y(1-x)$. From here I don't know how to deduce that $x = y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Let's expand both sides. We get

$$x-xy = y - xy.$$

Can you see how this implies $x=y$?

Comment: I have one more quick question. If $y \in [0, \infty)$, and I wanted to show that there is a surjection between $[0,1)$ and $[0, \infty)$, would consider $y = \displaystyle\frac{x}{(x+1)}$ and then proceed?

Comment: If you mean $y = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$, then yes. From there, you can solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac x{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}-1$$
$$\frac1{1-x}-1=\frac1{1-y}-1$$
$$\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{1-y}$$
$$1-x=1-y$$
$$x=y$$

Alternatively, the fact that $f(x)=\frac x{1-x}$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1)$ can be seen from the derivative $$f'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\gt0$$ or from the power series
$$f(x)=\frac1{1-x}-1=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots.$$